# Any efficient way to create a list from cells range in Python?

Tags: python, excel, row, cells

I have an Excel file and I have some parameters that I need to return in specific cell range, but different rows.

```
def get_list(row, start, stop):
    arr = list[start:stop] #and somewhere here I need to iterate throgh row because I store row separately.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You may use `xlswriter`, that you can specify each cells.

Comment: I just need to use range and iterate through row, I don't want to access each cells manually. Can you direct me?

Comment: the `pandas` package http://pandas.pydata.org/ allows you to manipulate `.csv` and `.xls` files handly

Comment: With using `csv` you will get an entire row and if you use the normal slicing on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the range for the following function. I'm using xlrd here.

```
import xlrd

def excel_reader(excel_name):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_name)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
    for i in range(sh.nrows):
        if i > 0:
            cell_value_class = int(sh.cell_value(i, 0))
            cell_value_id = int(sh.cell_value(i, 1))
            DataList[cell_value_class] = cell_value_id
```